# Is there any change in FireDAC exception EFDDBEngineException error code mapping for PostgreSQL?

Tags: delphi, postgresql-9.4, delphi-xe7, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

I have Delphi XE7 application which uses Postgres as a backend and Firedac for the database connection. When a database with the name `'db_name'` does not exist, Delphi XE 7 code generates a `EFDDBEngineException` class exception.

The type of this exception is `ekOther` and the Error code is 0.

```
// E.Kind  and E.ErrorCode
EFDDBEngineException
```

However when I migrated this application to Delphi 10.3.1, the error code is now returning as 1.  I could not find any reference to this change in Delphi 10.3.1 release documents.

My question is: Is it safe to change the Delphi 10.3.1 code to check for the error code 1 instead of 0?

```
// Delphi XE 7 code
if (E.Kind = ekOther) and (E.ErrorCode = 0) then begin
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have older Delphi version by hand, but in Delphi 10.3.2 the [`ErrorCode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDDBEngineException.ErrorCode) for PostgreSQL is set to the status returned by driver when the connection attempt is made and has value of [`CONNECTION_BAD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html) (which is declared as constant of value 1), when the attempt fails (which is returned by the [`PQstatus`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-status.html) function call).

However, this [`CONNECTION_BAD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html) status is returned for any kind of reason for connection attempt failure and the only way to get the details about such failure (even for PostgreSQL 12) is inspecting the error message (which is what FireDAC is doing for setting up relevant properties, like the [`Kind`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDDBEngineException.Kind) one, which you are testing).

That being said, to know whether the connection attempt failed due to non existing database reason, you'd have to parse the error message. Test you are doing does not guarantee this particular failure.

I can't answer your question as I don't have older version of Delphi by hand, but for the recent version of Delphi you can modify your code like follows (but as I said above it does not guarantee test for non existing database failure):

```
uses
  FireDAC.Phys.PGCli;

...
try
  FDConnection1.Open;
except
  on E: EPgNativeException do // or just EFDDBEngineException
    if (E.Kind = ekOther) and (E.ErrorCode = CONNECTION_BAD) then
      // connection attempt failed somehow, for details inspect the error message
end;
```